# How to get the latest update on any row?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a database table ABC with columns : ID, last_updated, Value, and more, So if there is any update on ID, then it inserts new row without deleting existing row with same ID, so How can I get the latest row for each IDs ?

e.g.

```
1,  20 march 2013,  45
1,  11 march 2012,  43
2,  12 march 2014,  10
3,   1 july  2014, 111
3,  17 march 2014, 112
```

So I want following result:

```
1,  20 march 2013,  45
2,  12 march 2014,  10
3,   1 july  2014, 111
```

Comment: You should consider adding a unique column (perhaps abc_id) that is auto incrementing and not affected by your trigger. It will simplify your queries.

Comment: I already have this table, I need to get latest updated date with value for each IDs.

Comment: I would also add another column "last" which is defaulted to false and a trigger that upon update "fixes" that column for the "previous last" and sets the new row with last=true

Answer (score 2):

```
Select *
from abc a
inner join (select id, max (last_updated) last_updated
            from abc
            group by id) b on a.id = b.id and a.last_updated = b.last_updated
```

Getting max date and grouping by id will give you the latest record. Then self joining that will give you all the records.

### Here is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c16d7/1)

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a famous query called ["groupwise maximum"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html). There are several ways to obtain the rows, here it is the solution without subqueries:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.last_updated, t1.value
FROM ABC t1
LEFT JOIN ABC t2 
ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.last_updated > t2.last_updated
WHERE t2.id IS NULL;
```